# istio How to configure services that use the root directory to convert to secondary paths

Tags: istio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XWpH.png)

How does my nginx configuration work in the isio? I need to be able to access pgadmin through the secondary path rather than through the root directory. The root directory will be used by other important servers

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your config file as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create istio gateway and istio virtual service objects.  Please refer istio documentation for [traffic management](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/).  Below is the sample of uri base routing and similarly you can add different routes based on the requirement.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - app.prod.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /pgadmin
    - route:
      - destination:
        host: <db service name>
```